# Couldn't find list workflows under my workflows

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, workflow

I have created two workflows, list and normal workflow.

I have saved and published both the workflows. But under my workflows in the site I can only see the normal workflow, I am not able to see the list workflow.

Why is it so? Is there any other settings that should be done for list workflow?

Comment: Did you check list settings / workflow settings?

Comment: what to check ..?

Comment: Check if both workflows exist?

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking in the browser under Site Settings >> Workflow Settings? This will only show site workflows. To see your list workflow you'd have to go to the Workflow Settings for the list.

If you're looking in Designer and one is missing, try going to Lists and Libraries, select the list, and see if the workflow shows up under the Workflows section.

[image]

[image]

Comment: in designer both list and site workflow is visible , only in browser list workflow is not visible

Comment: Make sure you published your workflow, and that if you are trying to start it manually that the tick in the workflow settings is checked to allow "manual start"

Comment: Yes that tick is checked . but i couldn't see the list workflow in browser

Comment: @dahsra Go to your list in the browser. In the ribbon, go to List Settings. Click Workflow Settings. Your list workflow will be here. You might have to choose a different content type from the dropdown, depending on which content type you built the workflow for.

Comment: In the ribbon, go to List Settings. Click Workflow Settings. where you mean in the designer or browser , because i couldn't find any ribbon in browser

Comment: What version of SharePoint are you in?

Comment: SHarepoint designer 2010

Comment: I'll add screenshots to my answer

Comment: Is the browser screen shot ..? Because in my browser i couldn't find any ribbons.!

Comment: Go here to chat: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38076/discussion-between-dahsra-and-erin-l